# Issues with Layout and Functionality After Removing a Button from a Slide Presentation Webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm facing some challenges while trying to remove a button from a slide presentation webpage and then redeploying it. Here's what I did:

1. I downloaded the HTML code.
2. I removed the corresponding button's HTML tag.
3. I saved the modified HTML code in a new document called "new.html."

However, after making these changes, I encountered the following problems:

1. The display of various elements on the page has changed unexpectedly.
2. I now only have slides, and the second one appears to be just a blank page.

I suspect that the issue might be related to the lengthy inline scripts and style sections in the code, but I'm not entirely sure.

Can anyone provide insights into what might be causing these problems and how I can go about resolving them?

Comment: Please share the code, anything else would be just a list of guesses from us. We don't want to debug symptoms, we debug source code. Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Create a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) where you reduce the code to only the part that is causing the issue. Also post errors you get, from the browser console or the developer tools network tab for example.